# Signal handling in mutlti-threaded process

Tags: c++, multithreading, signals

I have a basic problem of handling **signal** in a **multi-threaded** process.

In my code, I create one sub-thread from the main thread, to listen to a `SIGALRM` which will be later trigger by main thread (using other function like `timer_create` gives me the same result, so please don't focus on this).

**The problem** is, instead of catching the signal, the whole process terminated with a strange "Alarm clock" output on the console.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <csignal>

using namespace std;

void* run_something(void* args){
    //unblock the SIGALRM to be catched
    sigset_t sig;
    sigemptyset(&sig);
    sigaddset(&sig, SIGALRM);
    sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &sig, NULL); //tried with pthread_sigmask

    //wait for SIGALRM
    int catchedSig;
    sigwait(&sig, &catchedSig);
    cout<<"in sub-thread, SIGALRM catched, return"<<endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    //block SIGALRM in main thread
    sigset_t sig;
    sigemptyset(&sig);
    sigaddset(&sig, SIGALRM);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sig, NULL);

    //create new thread
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_create(&thread, &attr, run_something, NULL);

    //trigger SIGARLM after 2s
    alarm(2); //tried with timer_create/sigevent

    //wait
    cout<<"in main thread, waiting for sub-thread to terminate"<<endl;
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);
    cout<<"in main thread, terminating"<<endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Expected result**

- in main thread, waiting for sub-thread to terminate
- in sub-thread, `SIGALRM` getting caught, return
- in main thread, terminating

**Observed result**

- in main thread, waiting for sub-thread to terminate
- Alarm clock

**Additional info:**
I'm using g++ (Debian 5.4.0-4) 5.4.0 20160609.

Comment: I doubt the C++ behaviour regarding this issue differs from that of a C implementation. @CherubimAnand

Comment: @CherubimAnand: I think I would be useful for whom searching the same thing in C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `run_something` thread unblocks SIGALRM before calling `sigwait` for that signal, but [this is undefined behavior](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigwait.html).  `sigwait` removes a signal from the set of pending (i.e., *blocked*) signals.

Don't unblock in your thread and you'll see the behavior you expect.

Comment: Sry, for messing around in your answer, rolled it back!

Comment: The link to the `sigwait() docs  I wanted to add/update: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigwait.html

Answer (score 1):

The code shown does not set up any signal handler for `SIGARLM`.

Therefore on signal reception the OS does as it ought to, namely invoke [`SIGALRM`'s default action](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html), that is to terminate the process. Printing "Alarm clock" to the console is part of the default behaviour, BTW.

To fix this set up a signal handler for `SIGARLM`. This can be done in a portable manner by using [`sigaction()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html).

---

Also do not use [`sigprocmask()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigprocmask.2.html) in a multi-threaded program, as its behaviour is unspecified. Use [`pthread_sigmask()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_sigmask.html) instead.

---

**Update**:

I missed the code calls `sigwait()` ... :}

Under this condition fixing this issues does not raise the need to set up a signal handler (which still would solve the issue as well and is valid) but doing as proposed by [*pilcrow*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/132382/pilcrow)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38507857/694576), that is leave the signals blocked prior to calling `sigwait()`(or `sigwaitinfo()`).

*Additionally* make sure to use `pthread_sigmask()` instead of `sigprocmask()` for the reason given above.

---

*Unrelated to the question's issue*:

> I create one sub-thread from the main thread

There is no such concept as "sub"-threads. After having been created all process' threads are "siblings" on the same level. This includes the initial thread started using `main()`. The "main"-thread is commonly called this way just because of the name of it's thread-function: `main`

Comment: I'd say there is *one* difference to the "main" thread - upon `return()` from `main()` the process exits and all threads are terminated.  A `return()` from the function passed to `pthread_create()` will simply terminate that thread.  II feel that's important to add given how many questions I've seen posted asking why a process suddenly terminates when `main()` is used to start threads and then promptly calls `return()`.

Comment: Well yes, fair enough. Still, if `main()` ended with `pthread_exit()` there'd be *no* difference. @AndrewHenle